# how to go to main menu on click on submenu?

Tags: android, menu, submenu

how to go to main menu `onclick` on sub `menu` in android. i am trying this but unable to do that.

this is `java`

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    sub = menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu();
    sub.setHeaderTitle("sub menu...");
    sub.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_voice);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "submenu label=", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    TextView iv= (TextView) item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.action_settings);

    sub.getItem(0).setActionView(iv);
    Toast.makeText(this, "before onclick listener=", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "-submenu header title clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

this is my `menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Refresh" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_voice"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/change_password"
                android:title="change password" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/user_details"
                android:title="user details" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

[image]code

showing is `submenu` when we click on `submenu` text it should go back to `mainmenu`

Comment: implement  onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: try `<group>` option menu

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't provide some mechanism to set `onClickListener` to `SubMenu` header, but you can use a hack.

First of all, get rid of `SubMenu` header:

```
SubMenu sub = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getSubMenu(); 
sub.clearHeader();
```

It's not secure to use `getItem(0)`, because the order of your items may change, so I used `findItem(R.id.action_settings)` instead.

Next, you should add one more `item` to your `SubMenu`:

```
<menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sub_title"
            android:title="sub menu..."/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/change_password"
            android:title="change password" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/user_details"
            android:title="user details" />
</menu>
```

But now all three `items` will looks the same, so you need to change color of first `MenuItem`

```
MenuItem headItem = sub.findItem(R.id.sub_title);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(headItem.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, s.length(), 0);
headItem.setTitle(s);
```

Also, don't use `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` for that purposes, because it calls every time when you open `menu`, you can put all that code inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    SubMenu sub = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getSubMenu();
    sub.clearHeader();

    MenuItem headItem = sub.findItem(R.id.sub_title);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(headItem.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, s.length(), 0);
    headItem.setTitle(s);

    return true;
}
```

And the last step - listen to clicks on that `MenuItem`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.sub_title:
            Toast.makeText(this, "-submenu header title clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```